# How to terminate daemon thread in Android without force closing app?

Tags: android, daemon

I am using an android jar file in my android app. A method from that jar, when called, creates a daemon thread. My application is continuously running like service. I want to terminate that daemon without force closing my application whenever needed. How can I achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is 8 months old! You might want to make it as no loner active or flag and answer.

Answer (score 0):

maybe build a simple activity or a simple widget with one button that you can use to toggle your daemon?

Comment: But I don't know the ID or name of the daemon thread created by that method.

Answer (score 0):

you could create specific processes in your project. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html

Have one of your services be its own process that would get killed after you made the function call and did what you needed while the other part of your project would be unaffected.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have access to the source for the daemon thread, then you should be able to stop it with `Thread.interrupt();`

If you have the source code for your your daemon thread should wake up periodically to test its environment.
i.e. is should wake from whatever lock it has and run through its loop again.
Then you simply add a boolean inside the loop to check if it should terminate or not.

```
public void run(){
  running = true;
  while(running){
     // do your wait task
  }
}

public void cancel(){
    running = false;
}
```

A lot of things that block have a flag that defines how long to wait for, like ServerSocket for instance.

In general, basic Java teniques for thread handling work in Android as well, the main difference being that the harder you make the device work, the worse the batter performance. Here is a little reference that holds some information about stopping threads.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html

See the section on Thread.stop().